What LEGO set instructions do these 2 red and yellow brick bags come from?
The yellow and orange bag has 135149 on it, and the QR code comes up as 6351404.
The red and tan bricks bag say 2011 on it and also say 135149. There's also a smaller bag in the red and tan brick bag.


This question is similar to: How can I identify a set based on one or more original sealed bags?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@zovits ah I see, should I edit my question or is there a way to link it to the question you linked?

There is certainly no need to link anything. The question in the comment only serves as a pointer for anyone trying to conduct their own identification process - be it you, another answerer, or a reader in the future.

Based on Yellow Plate, Modified 4 x 4 with 2 x 2 Open Center, Yellow Plate 4 x 8, and Reddish Brown Brick 2 x 4, these can only be from 10696-1 Medium Creative Brick Box.

Wow! Thank you!

@Jinx You are certainly welcome :)
